# Bash: Save a file's current directory and concatanate it with this file while "find" is false?

Tags: bash

I would like to make a script, to add some files in a Makefile.

I would like to save the relative path from the Makefile to the file.

i was thinking to do something like this

```
file=$1
find Makefile
while [ $? -eq 1 ]
do
  ##"save current directory" ##
  ##"concatanate to $file" ##
  cd --
done
```

Comment: Are you looking for `find . -type f -name Makefile >>"$1"`? It's *really* not clear what you are trying to accomplish here, and code which doesn't do anything useful is not a good way of communicating what you do want.

Comment: i would like to have the relative path between my Makefile and my file
For example
if i run my code for "toto.c" in project/src/error/
i would like to have "project/src/error" because my Makefile is in /project. The final propose is to add inside my Makefile "project/src/error/toto.c"

Comment: Looks like [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
cd $1
while true; do
  if [ ! -f Makefile ]; then
    return 0
  fi
  echo $PWD
  cd ..
done
```

This will go to the arg directory and display directory till find a dir without Makefile

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to have this relative path in an other way

```
res=$(readlink -f $1)
echo "path of my file = $res"
find Makefile 2> /dev/null
while [ $? -eq 1 ]
do
    cd ..
    find Makefile 2> /dev/null
done
res2=$(pwd)
echo "$res2 is the Makefile path"
res=$(sed -i "s/$res2/.//g" <<< $res)
echo "the path becomes $res"
```

EDIT:
Thanks for answers, 
I've got my relative path from the Makefile directory to my file.
My problem is solved.

My code is now:

```
res=$(readlink -f $1)
echo "path of my file = $res"
while [ ! -f ./Makefile ]
do
    cd ..
done
res2=$(pwd)

echo "$res2 is the Makefile path"

res=$(echo "$res" | sed s\#"$res2"\#\#g)

echo "the path becomes $res"

VAR="\n\t\t\t$res\t\t\t\t\t\t\\\\"
sed -i -e "s/^SRC.*$/&$VAR/g" Makefile
printf "$1 added in Makefile\n"
```

My last sed doesn't work because my variable contain "/" and the trick on my first sed doesn't work on it. I'm a beginner in shell programming, this issue seems easy to fix. I'm looking for fix it on my own.
Thanks again !

Comment: Please provide a file/directory structure example and the desired output

Comment: The `while` is pretty hideous. You seem to want `while [ ! -f ./Makefile ]; do cd ..; done` roughly like in the other answer you have received.